# Conclusion from Stokes' Theorem

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

In my book there is a conclusion that if $S$ is a closed surface then
$$\oint_Srot\vec{A}\cdot d\vec{\sigma}=0$$
I don't understand why it's always equal to 0.

Comment: What do you know about the boundary of a closed surface and how does Stokes‘ theorem apply?

Comment: I understand Stokes' theorem overall. My suspicion is that an integral over a closed surface from a vector field is always 0 but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Stokes' theorem says that the integral of the curl of $A$ over a surface is equal to the line integral of $A$ over the boundary of the surface. But since $S$ is closed there is no boundary, so the integral is 0.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now.